# Embedding stack snippets inside codeblock

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

I noticed earlier on today that a snippet can be embedded inside a codeblock, resulting in a buggy rendering:

[image: snippet inside code]

Or, with an actual snippet:

```
    //And JS too!
    /*
     * And some CSS
    */
    <b>Look at me!</b>
```

While editing, if the snippet is indented like code, it shows up like

```
<pre>4325126b-0b59-b3d7-8010-a0aa9986f12e</pre>
```

It isn't that big of an issue, except:

1. It's really easy to reproduce(add a snippet, highlight,
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>)
2. If it is a longer snippet, there is a mess of scrollbars.

Comment: That's not a bug... that's just awesome

Comment: OLD MEME ALERT! Yo dawg, I heard you like Stack Snippets, so I put a Stack Snippet in your Stack Snippet.

Comment: I asked something similar on Meta Stack Exchange a while ago: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296441/349538